# Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo found in modules issue

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am facing this issue "Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallState found in modules jetified-app-update-2.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.1) and jetified-core-1.8.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0)" while installing debug build.
I am using **"sp-react-native-in-app-updates": "^1.1.1"** this library for in app updates.
Anyone who has solution?

Well I tried to clean gradlew. upgrading to new version. implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3' removed this from app.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the below code in dependencies section of android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation (project(':sp-react-native-in-app-updates')) 
{
  exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "app-update"
  exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "core"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code in app level gradle file, in native android development we follow these methods.

**Example 1:**

```
configurations {
   all {
      exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "app-update"
      exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "core"
  }
```

}

**Example 2:**

```
"sp-react-native-in-app-updates": "^1.1.1" {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "app-update"
    exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "core"
}
```